# How to get rid of a non integral exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How can we get rid of the exponent on the left side of the equation (knowing $y$)?
$$\large x^{0.997} = y$$

Thank you.

Comment: Show your efforts you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using power rules $x^{0.997}=y 
\implies x^{0.997^\frac{1}{0.997}} = y^{\frac{1}{0.997}} \implies x = y^{\frac{1}{0.997}}$